# how to use snapping?

Tags: modifiers, snapping

I use blender 2.9, i'm trying to create a donut, everything works fine until I try to stretch the vertices of the icing in order to create a dribbling icing, I used snapping face with project individual elements as I saw in a blender tutorial, nd when I come back to object mode the result isn't actually dribbling, it's like the icing shrink from the edge where I stretched

Answer (score 0):

Before and after pictures (or a video of you doing this) will help illustrate your question, but it sounds like you need to use '[proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html)'.